# Eucalyptus FastStart: NC detects wrong disk size

Tags: diskspace, eucalyptus, xfs

I installed the Eucalyptus FastStart Image to familiarize myself with Eucalyptus, but for some reason the NC doesn't detect the correct disk size:

```
from /var/log/eucalyptus/nc.log:
2015-04-03 17:49:56  INFO | disk space for instances: /var/lib/eucalyptus/instances/work
2015-04-03 17:49:56  INFO |                           014328MB limit (0.3% of the file system) - 260MB overhead = 14068MB = 13GB
2015-04-03 17:49:56  INFO |                           000000MB reserved for use (0.0% of limit)
2015-04-03 17:49:56  INFO |                           000000MB allocated for use (0.0% of limit, 0.0% of the file system)
2015-04-03 17:49:56  INFO |     disk space for cache: /var/lib/eucalyptus/instances/cache
2015-04-03 17:49:56  INFO |                           029093MB limit (0.7% of the file system)
2015-04-03 17:49:56  INFO |                           007168MB reserved for use (24.6% of limit)
2015-04-03 17:49:56  INFO |                           002296MB allocated for use (7.9% of limit, 0.1% of the file system)
```

My root-disk was to small for the /var/lib/ so I mounted another 4TB device to /var/lib/eucalyptus

```
# cat /etc/fstab | grep euca
/dev/mapper/vg_euca-lv_euca_data /var/lib/eucalyptus xfs    defaults        1 1

# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_hsun1-lv_root
                       50G  5.8G   41G  13% /
tmpfs                  64G  168K   64G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb1             477M   47M  406M  11% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_hsun1-lv_home
                       81G   56M   77G   1% /home
/dev/mapper/vg_euca-lv_euca_data
                      4.0T  4.2G  4.0T   1% /var/lib/eucalyptus
```

Is there something wrong with my /var/lib/eucalyptus mount? I unmounted this partition and checked the /var/lib/eucalyptus folder on / which is empty. So the NC can't work at the root partition.

In /etc/eucalyptus/eucalyptus.conf the INSTANCE_PATH is set to: "/var/lib/eucalyptus/instances"

Do you see whats wrong with my setup or do I deal with a bug here?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your /var/lib/eucalyptus mount of 4TB is fine.

Eucalyptus won't automatically grab the entire filesystem, at least beyond a certain size.

You may want to take a look at the NC's /etc/eucalyptus/eucalyptus.conf file. These sections should be present (unless you did a Faststart install):

https://github.com/eucalyptus/eucalyptus/blob/e363faae31a26fe630c353a88638db4bf51153a9/tools/eucalyptus.conf#L102-110

Check out the (commented-out) NC_WORK_SIZE and NC_CACHE_SIZE settings. Uncomment them, and set them as appropriate (per the comments noted within the baseline eucalyptus.conf file, linked-to above).

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. I used a faststart installation, therefore all the options in /etc/eucalyptus/eucalyptus.conf are missing.

I added the following to the file:
NC_WORK_SIZE=2048000,
NC_CACHE_SIZE=1024000

Now the NC uses 2TB for instances and 1TB for it's cache. It was a easy solution, hope this helps someone else having this problem.
Thanks again!